# finding all $z$ such that $f(z)=g(z)=h(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

Suppose I have three functions $f(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $g(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and $h(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

What  methods work for finding all $z$ such that $f(z)=g(z)=h(z)$?
Variants of Newton-Raphson are acceptable, but I'm having difficulty encoding  it.

Answer (score 3):

See [Computing the Zeros of Analytic Functions](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+%26+engineering/book/978-3-540-67162-6) for theory and code.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ and $g$ are both holomorphic and are not the same function, then the set $\{z\mid f(z)=g(z)\}$ consists of at most countably many isolated points. Find those points by solving $f(z)-g(z)=0$ in whichever way works for those two functions, and then check each of them to see whether $f(z)=h(z)$.